# Ubuntu Desktop Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS runs out of memory after sometime and cfrashes

Tags: 22.04, crash, memory-leak

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 and then updated to 22.04.1. My machine has been crashing ever since I moved to 22.04. I noticed that the memory utilization gradually increases overtime, even if I am not running any application (other than System Monitor or Top command on Terminal). This happens gradually over 3-4 hours and then the system crashes. This did not happen with the previous version of Ubuntu Desktop.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: What exact commands are you using to see the memory usage increasing and that it is out of memory.

Comment: I use `top` command via command line and also System Monitor App (Resource tab) to track the memory utilization. On System Monitor App, if I sort processes by memory utilization, I don't see one specific process hogging up the memory, however, overtime, I see the memory utilization gradually spike even if I don't perform any other task on the machine except keep System Monitor running.

Comment: I saw this patch (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1983498) just come through for my machine. Hope this address the issue; looks like a long running one.

Comment: The afore mentioned patch did not fix the issue. Re-installed Ubuntu Desktop 21.10 and I no longer see the issue. Hopefully it will be resolved in 22.04 in future fixes.